# How do I use Javascript to blur a background image?

Tags: javascript, css, image

My users upload background images.  These images are stored in CDN on Amazon S3 (not on the same server).

Currently, the way I do the background is this.

```
<div id="background"></div>
```

It's position fixed, and I use javascript to set the background-image.

I would like to BLUR this background on the client side.  How can I do this?

Blur.js does not work with an image on Amazon CDN.

Comment: Would you be able to blur the image server side, once it's uploaded, then point to the blurred image instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try using the Pixastic library (as long as you don't mind using HTML5 features):

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/

Answer (score 0):

You can use css filters to do this, but only in super new browsers. That and a combo of SVG filters will get you a few browsers. I guess you could then fall back to canvas, and excanvas to get almost all browsers.

Really, I'd just use filters, in a year or so most users will have them.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can use style.filter, see example below:

```
var element = document.getElementById("background");

element.style.filter = "blur(0px)";
```

Tested on Chrome Version 86.0.4240.198 (Official Build) (x86_64) and it works.